# I am getting 'assertCookie' failed errors in the Lithium Test Dashboard

Tags: php, unit-testing, cookies, frameworks, lithium

I installed a fresh Li3 using this command from the installationguide:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist unionofrad/framework project

Afterwards i ran all tests to see if Lithium is working correctly and got the following errors in the Lithium Test Dashboard:

> Assertion 'assertCookie' failed in lithium\tests\cases\storage\session\adapter\CookieTest::testWriteDefaultParameters() on line 79:
>   /^Set-Cookie:\s[\w.-]+[write]=value+to+be+written;\sexpires=Mon, 10-Oct-2016 14:17:34 GMT;\spath=// - Cookie not found in headers.
>
> Assertion 'assertCookie' failed in lithium\tests\cases\storage\session\adapter\CookieTest::testWriteArrayData() on line 104:
>   /^Set-Cookie:\s[\w.-]+[user][email]=test%40localhost;\sexpires=Mon, 10-Oct-2016 14:17:34 GMT;\spath=// - Cookie not found in headers.
>
> Assertion 'assertCookie' failed in lithium\tests\cases\storage\session\adapter\CookieTest::testWriteArrayData() on line 108:
>   /^Set-Cookie:\s[\w.-]+[user][address][country]=Iran;\sexpires=Mon, 10-Oct-2016 14:17:34 GMT;\spath=// - Cookie not found in headers.
>
> Assertion 'assertCookie' failed in lithium\tests\cases\storage\session\adapter\CookieTest::testWriteCustomParameters() on line 149:
>   /^Set-Cookie:\s[\w.-]+[write]=value+to+be+written;\sexpires=Sun, 09-Oct-2016 14:17:34 GMT;\spath=// - Cookie not found in headers.

How can i solve these issues to have a clean running Li3?